# IndexError: list index out of range [Django, python, object, filter]

Tags: python, django

Делаю выборку `objects.filter` и используя `values()[0]` преобразуя результат в `dict`

**views**

```
device = 'some text'
qry = Device.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=device)).values()[0]
```

если в базе есть в наличии запись, то создается `dict`, если ничего не находит, выводит `IndexError: list index out of range`

Надо ловить отсутствие выборки исключением или как?

Comment: Если вам нужен всего один объект, то используйте `.first()` наверное?

Comment: Можно проверять `len(Device.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=device)).values())`, если `0`, то ничего нет, иначе нулевой элемент точно будет.

Comment: @V-Mor это не оч хорошо, ибо будет запрос без LIMIT 1, когда нужен только 1 элемент